# Increase Max POST variable length in Apache server

Tags: php, apache

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/787158),

> The official Apache documentation only mentions an 8,192-byte limit on
>   an individual field in a request.

How to increase the size of the individual field, Just being curious here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can configure this with the [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline). If you want it above the 8190 limit you need to change the source code of Apache and recompile it as of below statement from Apache:

> Under normal conditions, the value should not be changed from the
>   default.  Also, you can't set this higher than 8190 without modifying
>   the source and rebuilding.